# Access private methods from outside a class

Tags: php, visibility

I have a `Bcrypt.class` which contains my hashing methods and I have a `userDAO.class` which contains my register method.

In my `Bcrypt.class` the methods are private. How can I access them in my `userDAO.class` so I can hash my password?

Please let me know if you need to see any code.

Comment: If you want them to be used from another class, make them public.

Comment: Make them public or make them static so you can call it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `private` methods from outside of the class declaring them. If API developer decided to use `private` then there is no chance. I personally prefer `protected` in almost every situation. Some API developers don't..

If you have personal access to the source code of the `Bcrypt` class and you can change it without breaking anything then make the methods either `protected` and extend the class or make them even `public`

Another design approach would be to place the algorihms in a separate class and use them in the `Bcrypt` class and others

Answer (score 1):

Make your methods in the **`Bcrypt`** class either **`public`** or **`protected`**.

These are things you should keep in mind.

- **`Public Methods`** : Can be accessed from anywhere
- **`Protected Methods`** : Can be accessed by the class and other classes that inherits it.
- **`Private Methods`** : Only the corresponding will have access.

Comment: So what's actually the benefit of your answer compared to my existing one?

Comment: I didn't even look at your answer whilst i answered mine.

Comment: Normally it goes: Read the question, look at the answers. If the question has already an answer and you confirm with -> upvote, went over to the next question.

Comment: Nothing to whine about, your answer is on the top. So chill up.

Comment: No worry I'm chilled.. But try to think before you post

Comment: @DipeshParmar undeleted. :)

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.4 and [ReflectionMethod::getClosure()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getclosure.php) it looks like accessing private methods from the outside is possible. To be honest - had to try out the following solution before believing it actually works.

Code from the [User Contributed Notes section by Denis Doronin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getclosure.php#111140).

```
function call_private_method($object, $method, $args = array()) 
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($object));
    $closure = $reflection->getMethod($method)->getClosure($object);
    return call_user_func_array($closure, $args);
}

class Example 
{

    private $x = 1;
    private $y = 10;

    private function sum() 
    {
        print $this->x + $this->y;
    }

}

call_private_method(new Example(), 'sum');

// Output is 11.
```